# Winsock-bind function error In MASM(32 BIT asm)

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, winsock, masm32

First of all, Im sorry for my bad english, english isn't my first language.
So, I'm trying to write chat program in Assembly 32 BIT, MASM.

Right Now, I'm writing the server side code, So far I used the WSAStartUp and Socket - Windows API functions, and Now im trying to use the Bind function.

The link for the bind function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550(v=vs.85).aspx

This is the code that I have written so far(My problem is written after the code):

```
.386 
.MODEL Flat, STDCALL 
option casemap:none 

include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\Ws2_32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\Ws2_32.lib
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib

.DATA 

Success db 'WSAStartUp Succseed!',0
NO_Success db 'WSAStartUp NOT Succseed....',0
Socketsu db 'Socket :(:(:(:(',0
SocketSuccess db 'Socket Success!! :)',0
Bindno db 'Bind Error',0
Bindyes db 'Bind Success! :)',0
LocalIP db "127.0.0.1",0
port dd 8020

.DATA? 

wsadata db 400 dup (?)      ;WSADATA struct that hold the information about the Windows Sockets implementation.(info ret from WSATSTARTUP)
flag dw ?
ListenSocket dd ?
SockAddrStruct db 30 dup (?)
;so sockaddr_in <?> 
sockaddrs db 16 dup (?)

.CONST 
    wVersionRequested equ 0101h
.CODE 
   main:
;-------------------WSAStartUp-----------------------;
        ;Initialize the work with winsock (WS StartUp = WINSOCK START UP)

             invoke WSAStartup,wVersionRequested, offset wsadata        
            .if eax!=0
                invoke MessageBoxA,NULL,offset NO_Success,offset NO_Success,MB_OK 
                jmp End_Program
            .else
                invoke MessageBoxA,NULL,offset Success,offset Success,MB_OK 
            .endif

;-------------------Socket-----------------------;

    ;AF_INET - address family(in format: host,port) to likboa the type of addresses that the socket can communicate with

    invoke socket,AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP
    .IF eax==INVALID_SOCKET
        invoke MessageBoxA,NULL,offset Socketsu,offset Socketsu,MB_OK 
        jmp End_Program
     .else
       invoke MessageBoxA,NULL,offset SocketSuccess,offset SocketSuccess,MB_OK
       mov [ListenSocket],eax
    .ENDIF
;-------------------Bind-------------------------;
;SockAddr Struct:

mov eax,AF_INET
mov [dword ptr sockaddrs],eax
invoke htons,[port]
mov [dword ptr sockaddrs+2],eax
invoke inet_addr,[dword ptr LocalIP]   
mov [dword ptr sockaddrs+4],eax
invoke bind,SIZEOF sockaddrs,offset sockaddrs,ListenSocket

.if eax==0
    invoke MessageBoxA,NULL,offset Bindyes,offset Bindyes,MB_OK
.else
    invoke MessageBoxA,NULL,offset Bindno,offset Bindno,MB_OK
.endif


End_Program:
        invoke ExitProcess,0 
end main
```

I don't know what is the problem. But when I run the code I'm getting the MessageBox that I Built that says:Bind Error.

I guess that this is a problem in sockaddrs struct (the way that I put values in to it). But I don't know what do I need to change and how to fix it.

I thought maybe to use WSAGetLastError Function to see what is the Error but I don't know how to print the value that the function returns and see what is the error(I can't put in the invoke MessageBox, a parameter EAX(the register that hold the value that returns)) .

So can someone help me fix the problem In the 'Bind' part?

Comment: You can use the `wsprintf` function to format your error code into a string that you can show in a messagebox or write to a debug console. Refer to the masm32 headers for the `wsprintf` prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### WSAGetLastError

You have a couple questions. I'll start by giving you one method of retrieving a message representing the last `WSAGetLastError` (it also works with `GetLastError`). The Win32 API way is to use `FormatMessage` to convert the error message code returned by `WSAGetLastError`. Information from MSDN on *FormatMessage* can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx), along with an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582(v=vs.85).aspx) similar to the code we'll use. It is defined as:

> DWORD WINAPI FormatMessage(
>
> > In     DWORD   dwFlags,
> >     In_opt LPCVOID lpSource,
> >     In DWORD   dwMessageId,
> >     In  DWORD  dwLanguageId,
> >     Out LPTSTR  lpBuffer,
> >     In DWORD   nSize,
> >     In_opt va_list *Arguments
> >     );

In your `.DATA?` area, add a variable to store the buffer pointer that we'll return from `FormatMessage`:

```
lpErrorMsg  dd  ?
```

To then retrieve and display the last WSA error you can use something like this after a socket related call (like `bind`):

```
.if eax==SOCKET_ERROR
    invoke WSAGetLastError
    invoke FormatMessageA, FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM or FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, NULL, eax, LANG_NEUTRAL, offset lpErrorMsg, 0, NULL
    invoke MessageBoxA,NULL,lpErrorMsg,offset Bindno,MB_OK
.endif
```

### Bug Fixing

There are a number of problems in your code. The first one I observed was that `port` need to be a 32 bit Integer so it should be defined as:

```
port dd 8020
```

Without this change `htons` will not work properly as it is expecting a 32-bit Integer.

The next bug is here:

```
invoke MessageBoxA,NULL,offset SocketSuccess,offset SocketSuccess,MB_OK
mov [ListenSocket],eax
```

You are clobbering `eax` by calling `MessageBoxA` first. You probably meant to save it first:

```
mov [ListenSocket],eax
invoke MessageBoxA,NULL,offset SocketSuccess,offset SocketSuccess,MB_OK
```

There appear to be a number of issues in this code:

```
mov eax,AF_INET
mov [dword ptr sockaddrs],eax
```

This is incorrect as it works with 32-bit *Integer* and we need a *WORD*(16-bit). It should be:

```
mov ax,AF_INET
mov [word ptr sockaddrs],ax
```

This also required to use a 16-bit *WORD* to be stored at `sockaddrs+2` :

```
invoke htons,[port]
mov [dword ptr sockaddrs+2],eax
```

So should have been:

```
invoke htons,[port]
mov [word ptr sockaddrs+2],ax
```

This is incorrect since we don't want to de-reference what is at LocalIP, we just want LocalIP's address:

```
invoke inet_addr,[dword ptr LocalIP]   
mov [dword ptr sockaddrs+4],eax
```

So this seems to be more correct:

```
invoke inet_addr, offset LocalIP   
mov [dword ptr sockaddrs+4],eax
```

You then mixed up the parameters to `bind`. You had:

```
invoke bind,SIZEOF sockaddrs,offset sockaddrs,ListenSocket
```

It should have been:

```
invoke bind,ListenSocket,offset sockaddrs,SIZEOF sockaddrs
```

### Easier way to work with sockaddr_in

*MASM32* defines a `sockaddr_in` with all the fields defined. To make working with this structure easier and to make the code more readable, you might want to consider altering `SockAddrStruct` to be defined as (and zeroed out):

```
SockAddrStruct sockaddr_in <0>
```

With `SockAddrStruct` defined this way you can now change your socket code to read something like this:

```
;-------------------Bind-------------------------;
;SockAddr Struct:

mov SockAddrStruct.sin_family,AF_INET
invoke htons, [port]
mov SockAddrStruct.sin_port,ax
invoke inet_addr, offset LocalIP   
mov SockAddrStruct.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr, eax
invoke bind,ListenSocket,offset SockAddrStruct,SIZEOF SockAddrStruct
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I really Appreciate your help! but one question, how did you know for example that AF_INET needs 16 bit, to put the offset of LocalIP to inet_addr, that htons returns to ax the value and not to eax and so on.. I mean, where those things are written? because in MSDN site it didn't mantion.. can you please explain me how did you find those information? and again THANK you!

Comment: @RoyKuper Good question. You can't really rely on MSDN but you have to view the MASM32 include files. For instance if you look up `htons` in the file `\masm32\include\ws2_32.inc` and you will see that the parameter is listed as `DWORD`. You will actually find that with MASM32 all the Win32 API calls require `DWORD` parameters. So you have to be careful what you pass.

Comment: @RoyKuper Now as for knowing the size of the fields of `sockaddr_in` and whether they are 16 or 32 bit, that structure is defined in `masm32\include\windows.inc ` . Just review each field and it will tell you what size each is (_BYTE_, _WORD_, _DWORD_) etc

Comment: @RoyKuper And it is always best to search through the _MASM32_ include files because the names sometimes don't match the MSDN documentation. Try to find a tool that searches through all the files in a directory. It comes in handy trying to find out which include file contains what. I have yet to see a nice and neat webpage that provides all the structures and their location in the MASM include files to use as a cross reference tool to find this type of thing faster.

Comment: Okey Cool, I really appreciate your help, you helped me a lot! I'll take your tips and make it. Have a good week!

Comment: @RoyKuper : if you eventually get your code to work later in the week, and if this answer helped solved your issues please comeback and accept the answer. You can read about the how and why of accepting answers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you are new to Stackoverflow. Good luck!